# Substitute symbol name in macro

Tags: emacs, lisp-macros

How can I substitute a symbol name into a function created in a macro?  I think I am missing something obvious here.  For example, I am trying to make a macro that defines some variables and functions similar to the following,

```
(cl-defmacro mac (pkg)
  (let (
        ;; Define some variables
        (sym (intern (concat pkg "-file")))
        (sym-def "default-file.el")
        (sym-doc (concat "A custom var from `" pkg "'."))
        ;; Define some functions
        (symfn (intern (concat pkg "-fn")))
        (symfn-doc (concat "A function for `" pkg "'.")))

    `(list
      (defcustom ,sym ,sym-def ,sym-doc
        :group (quote ,(make-symbol pkg))
        :type '(choice (const :tag "None" nil)
                       file))
      (defun ,symfn ()
        ,symfn-doc
        (interactive)
        (fn ,sym)))))
```

The function returned makes a call out to another function (`fn`) with a signature like

```
(defun fn (var) (symbol-value var))
```

So, it is expecting a call like `(fn 'some-var)`.  And, I want to be able to use the macro like

```
(mac "pack")
```

And have the following work,

```
pack-file  ; works: "default-file.el"
(pack-fn)  ; error: not a symbol
```

I have tried things like `(quote ,sym)`, `symbol-name`, and others... But can't seem to get it right.

Comment: The expansion of your macro should probably be a `progn` form, for one thing.  You probably want the call to `fn` to be `(fn ',sym)`.  (I don't have anything with elisp on it to hand, but the rest looks OK).

Comment: You mentioned it in the question, so I bet it was finger trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the call to `fn` to be `(fn ',sym)` (which you mention you tried in the question, but I suspect got wrong somehow).

You probably also want the expansion of the macro to be `(progn ...)` instead of `(list ...)`.

(This was originally a comment: I'm putting it here just so there's an answer.)